# How do I use external assembly with BCC

Tags: compiler-errors, turbo-c

I have a VERY basic main.c program that I'm trying to compile, but I cannot get it to compile with a simple external assembly function.

Let me show you what I have

**main.c:**

```
extern void putc(char c);

int main()
{
    return (0);
}
```

**Terminal:**

```
$ bcc -c main.c
main.c:13.21: error: need ')'
main.c:13.24: error: c not in argument list
main.c:13.24: error: need ';'
main.c:13.24: error: need '{'
main.c:13.24: error: bad expression
main.c:15.3: error: bad expression
main.c:15.8: error: need ';'
main.c:16.1: error: need ';'
main.c:17.15: error: compiler bug? - attempting to load non-scalar non-pointer
main.c:eof: error: need '}'
$
```

**UPDATE:**
If I change the code to

```
extern void putc(c) char c;

int main();
{
    return(0);
}
```

Then I just get

```
$ bcc -c main.c 
main.c:8.11: error: main not in argument list
main.c:10.14: error: compiler bug? - attempting to load non-scalar non-pointer
$
```

Comment: Is there anything below the lines you posted? (they are less than 13 lines, but from what I can understand from the output, the errors appear on lines 13, 15 and so on).

Comment: There are comments in the actual code, but other than commented lines there is nothing else. `extern void putc` is line 13

Comment: Could you give it a try with `extern void putc(char);`? IIRC both forms `extern type foo(type arg);` and `extern type foo(type)` should be acceptable, but probably the first one annoys bcc.

Comment: then I get, `main.c:6.21: error: need ')'
main.c:6.22: error: need variable name
main.c:6.23: error:  not in argument list
main.c:eof: error: need '{'
main.c:eof: error: need '}'`

Comment: Apparently it needs the `-ansi` option -- I just managed to compile your example with `bcc -ansi -c main.c`. If you can, give it a try and see how it goes

Comment: Yeah... I did notice that the code would compile with ANSI, but I was trying to avoid using ANSI. But, I'll add an update for what I found.